# how to make dynamic scope iteration in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

i have scope like this in my controller

```
$scope.chats1 ={user_name:item.user_name,user_photo:item.user_photo}
$scope.chats2 ={user_name:item.user_name,user_photo:item.user_photo}
$scope.chats3 ={user_name:item.user_name,user_photo:item.user_photo}
```

And this is my currently ng-repeat:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="x in chats1"></li>
<li ng-repeat="x in chats2"></li>
<li ng-repeat="x in chats3"></li>
</ul>
```

My question is how to make single ng-repeat that contains all of my scope like this

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in chats"> /* defines $scope.chats1,$scope.chats2,$scope.chats3 */
</li>
 </ul>
```

Thank You and i'm really appreciate ur help

Comment: ng-repeat is on array not object... if you want to use ng-repeat on object you have to push that in array.

Comment: if you want to show one abject in array user "array[index]"

Comment: ahh i see thanks for ur comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple just push your scope objects in an array, call it chats.And repeat on it. The whole code would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="hcApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller = "hcAppCtrl">
    chats: {{chats}}
    <br>
    <br>
    <div ng-repeat="data in chats">{{data.user_name}}</div>

<script>
angular.module('hcApp',[])
.controller('hcAppCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope){

  $scope.chats1 ={user_name:"alex",user_photo:"awesome"}
  $scope.chats2 ={user_name:"rumba",user_photo:"damn"}
  $scope.chats3 ={user_name:"sunil",user_photo:"hero"}
  var temp = [];

  temp.push($scope.chats1,$scope.chats2,$scope.chats3);

  $scope.chats =temp;
}]); 
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is the working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/AByjditVwjJzbcMTkS7T?p=preview

Comment: Pleasure is all mine :)